# Conditional won't execute properly

Tags: python, python-2.x

I wonder if you could help me with the code below:

```
min = None
max = None
while True:
    input = raw_input("Please enter number: ")
    if input == "done":
        break
    else:
        try:
            input = float(input)
        except:
            continue



    if max < input:
        max = input
    elif min > input:
        min = input

    print min
    print max
```

It looks right to me, but the elif statement which gives a value to min always prints `None`. Could you please explain why?

Comment: You never assign a value to `max`.

Comment: Why would you even compare numbers to `None` in the first place?

Comment: By the way, by assigning values to `min`, `max` and `input`, you overwrite three builtin functions.

Answer (score 4):

`None > number` is never true, because Python 2 sorts `None` before any other type. Don't compare numbers with `None`.

Either test for `None` explicitly, or replace `None` with an infinity value.

Testing for `None`:

```
if max is None or max < input:
    max = input
elif min is None or min > input:
    min = input
```

Setting the values to positive or negative infinity:

```
min = float('inf')
max = float('-inf')
```

By setting `min` to positive infinity, *any other number* is guaranteed to be smaller; the same applies to `max` negative infinity.

Comment: It should also be noted that both `min` and `max` are reserved names in Python, and should avoid being used as variable names.

Comment: @ChristianDean: they are **not** reserved. There are built-in functions that are masked by using the names, but that's not disallowed.

Comment: I know that. When I said "reserved", I meant "reserved" as in _"reserved for specific values"_, not that it's disallowed to use them. But I agree, my wording was confusing. I'll use builtin instead.

Comment: @ChristianDean: 'reserved' is usually used for [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), of which there thankfully are not many.

Answer (score 0):

Your `min > input` is always going to be false if `min` is `None`, hence why it never gets set.

Also you don't want the `elif`.  The first number is both the min and the max.

Fixed:

```
min = None
max = None
while True:
    input = raw_input("Please enter number: ")
    if input == "done":
        break
    else:
        try:
            input = float(input)
        except:
            continue



    if max is None or max < input:
        max = input
    if min is None or min > input:
        min = input

    print min
    print max
```

Good luck!